# Passing props from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a little bit stuck, cause I don't understand the logic in the end of passing the props.

I have 2 components

This is my Items inside a dropdown component

```
const DropdownItem = (props) => {
    let companies = [
        {
            id: 1, name: "Tesla", owner: "Elon Musk"
        },
        {
            id: 2, name: "Space X", owner: "Also Elon"
        },
        {
            id: 3, name: "Some X", owner: "Also Kanye"
        },
    ]
    let dropdownElements = companies.map(c =>
        <DropdownItem id={c.id} name={c.name} owner={c.owner}/>
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <a href="#" className="menu-item">
                <span className="icon-button"></span>
                {companies[0].name}
            </a>
        </div>
    );
}

export default DropdownItem;
```

And here is DropdownMenu it self

```
const DropdownMenu = (props) => {
    return (

        <div className="dropdown">
            <DropdownItem />
            <DropdownItem />
            <DropdownItem />
        </div>
    );
}

export default DropdownMenu;
```

As you can see I'm creating 3 components to showcase it in the dropdownmenu, but the issue is that they are not responsive. So in my dropdown look like that.

How I can pass this `{dropdownElements}` correctly, cause when I try to add it instead of 3x `<DropdownItem />` I receive empty dropdown with no Items at all.

Where I miss the logic in passing the props?

In the whole end I would like to manage state with Redux, but currently I just want to understand why I can't make it right, any suggestion how to pass the element that it can be responsive?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically, you turn the wrong way from the beginnig. You need to iterate data via the Array.map and inside of map method return your component on each map iteration. This is the only way you can pass your props to component in your case, also don't forget to define key property for each data item.

```
const DropdownMenu = (props) => {
     let companies = [
        {
            id: 1, name: "Tesla", owner: "Elon Musk"
        },
        {
            id: 2, name: "Space X", owner: "Also Elon"
        },
        {
            id: 3, name: "Some X", owner: "Also Kanye"
        },
    ]
    return (
            <div className="dropdown">
                {companies.map((c) => (
                    <DropdownItem key={c.id} name={c.name} owner={c.owner} />
                ))}
            </div>
        );
}

export default DropdownMenu;
```

so, in your DropdownItem must be something like:

```
const DropdownItem = ({name, owner}) => <div>{name} {owner}</div>
```

Comment: OH daaaaamn, thanks for explanation, I changed it a little bit, i move map method to another variable and just render a variable in divs. But still thanks a lot for giving me a point!